# Increase a certain cell reference by 1

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this formula to count the word Moderator through different tabs in an Excel sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&'2020_01_09'!Z$1:Z$21&"'!E5"),"Moderator"))
```

Instead of changing the cell reference E5 to E6, E7 and so on manually, I would like to increase it by Auto-fill. No matter what I try, it does not increase at all. It stays E5.

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

**UNTESTED**    try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&'2020_01_09'!Z$1:Z$21&"'!E" & ROWS($1:5)),"Moderator"))
```

and copy downwards.